# LINQ with Subquery and left join

Tags: linq, subquery, ef-core-2.1

I am trying to write LINQ query to generate below SQL query. I know it looks like assignment, but tried few syntax which generated wrong query.

```
select pm.Profile_Number,PD.Line_Abbrev,PD.Group_Code from Profile_Detail PD
INNER JOIN  Profile_Master PM ON pd.profile_id = pm.profile_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Field_Abbr,Group_Code FROM vw_Group_Code
    where ((US=1 AND Group_US_Obsolete <> 1) OR (CA=1 AND Group_CA_Obsolete <> 1) OR (MX=1 AND Group_MX_Obsolete <> 1))

)gcv ON PD.Line_Abbrev = gcv.Field_Abbr AND PD.Group_Code = gcv.Group_Code
WHERE PD.Profile_Id IN(42) AND gcv.Field_Abbr IS NULL
```

Tried version :

```
(from pd in _context.ProfileDetail
                                                           join pm in _context.ProfileMaster on pd.ProfileId equals pm.ProfileId
                                                           join vla in _context.VwLineAbbrvs on pd.LineAbbrev equals vla.LineAbbrev into gc
                                                           from vla in gc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                           where profileNumber.Contains(pd.ProfileId.ToString()) &&
                                                           ((vla.IsUS && vla.USObsolete) || (vla.IsCA && !vla.CAObsolete) || (vla.IsMX && !vla.MXObsolete))
                                                           select new ObsoleteLineDetail
                                                           {
                                                               LineAbbrv = pd.LineAbbrev,
                                                               GroupCode = pd.GroupCode,
                                                               ProfileNumber = pm.ProfileNumber
                                                           }).ToList();
```

Comment: Please post the generated SQL query for your Linq.

Comment: Maybe EF core doesn't support to use Subqueries on right join to be used as where condition in mail query.

Comment: If you've got a specific SQL statement in mind and you're struggling to generate it with LINQ. Then just forget LINQ and execute the query you want to run. LINQ is there to make your life easier not to be an obstacle.